# How can I customize the "Cancel Chat" button to show a better "disconnected" style?

Tags: liveagent, deployment-api

The "Cancel Chat" button does cancel the connection, but it doesn't appear disconnected to the user. It appears like it's still trying to make a connection. Any way to customize it?

[image]